# Concerning the absoluteness of the powerset

Tags: set-theory

Are the following relations absolute, absolute downward, absolute upward or nothing?

1. $y=P(x)$
2. $y$ is a subset of $P(x)$

Comment: Welcome to SE.Mathematics! What are $x$ and $y$? What is $P$? What are your attempts?

Comment: P is the power set, x and y are sets: so my question would be if the following relations are absolute:1.) y=P(x) and 2.) y \subset P(x). Moreover if 2 is delta-0 formula, 1 should also be a delta 0 formula right?

Comment: No because in 2 you only have to quantify over elements of $y$ whereas in 1) you also have to express that every $z$ of the universe that is a subset of $x$ is in $y$. Thus it is $\Pi_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) is not absolute since we can move $P(x)$ by forcing.

2) is absolute because it's $\Delta_0$

Comment: Could you provide me a counterexample for 1.) ?

Comment: Well, start from a countable transitive model of ZFC+V=L and add new subsets of $\omega$ by forcing.